# Sysdate as string

Tags: mysql, jsp, prepared-statement, sysdate

I´m sending to server string `sysdate()`from an android device. The problem is that the code doesnt insert anything to mysql database. The column `first` is `DATETIME`. I´m using mysql workbench, when i type `INSERT INTO test (first) VALUES (sysdate());` in the workbench, it works.

```
<%
     String t = request.getParameter("time");
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            int updateQuery = 0;
            if (t != null) {
                if (t != "" ) {
                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                        String queryString1 = "INSERT INTO test (first) VALUES (?)";
                        pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString1);
                        pstatement.setString(1, t);
                        updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
                        if (updateQuery != 0) {
                            response.setStatus(400);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        out.println(ex);

                    } finally {
                        pstatement.close();
                        connection.close();
                    }
                } 
            } 
        %>
```

Comment: What does the date look like when it comes from Android? In other words, what's the value of your variable `t`? Is it `3/29/2013`? `2013-03-29`? Also, do you actually have a console to view the exception that's output in your `catch`? You could check that.

Comment: It looks like `sysdate()`. I dont converting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Java is very rusty, but nobody else has jumped in so I'll give this a try. I remember dates being tricky with JDBC.

Here are two attempts, but be warned that they're untested because I don't have the setup right now to test them.

**Approach #1**: pass the date as a string and have MySQL convert it. Instead of this for your `INSERT` statement:

```
String queryString1 = "INSERT INTO test (first) VALUES (?)";
```

... try this:

```
String queryString1 = "INSERT INTO test (first) VALUES (str_to_date(?, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))";
```

---

**Approach #2**: use `PreparedStatement.setDate` instead of `PreparedStatement.setString`. *Note that this uses your original INSERT statement, not the one proposed in Approach 1*. This means converting the string date `t` to a `java.util.Date` and then to a `java.sql.date`.

Instead of this for your `set`:

```
pstatement.setString(1, t);
```

... try this:

```
// Change string to java.util.Date
java.util.Date dt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.ENGLISH).parse(t);

// Change java.util.Date to java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date sqlDt = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());

// Set parameter as a date
pstatement.setDate(1, sqlDt);
```

Comment: You're welcome! I haven't used Java for years (a shame because I like it) so I was worried I might do more harm than good with my answer. I'm glad it helped :)